# Use request value from list of values in JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, web-testing

I'm sure I've already done this in the past but somehow I cannot figure out how ;-) 
So, here's my problem:

I'm trying to create a JUnit test plan in which a HTTP request is modified each iteration by altering a specific parameter. So, for example in five iterations I want the following HTTP requests to be made:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/foo.html?id=1
http://localhost:8080/test/foo.html?id=2
http://localhost:8080/test/foo.html?id=3
http://localhost:8080/test/foo.html?id=4
...
```

I want to configure the identifier values globally for the test plan and use them within the HTTP request samplerer like this:

```
Path: /test/foo.html?id=${categoryId}
```

The question now:  How do I configure the identifiers values globally (I do *not* want to use `StringFromFile`) and how do I reference them in the sampler?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

- If you're only incrementing, you can use a [counter element](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter)
- You can use [any number of functions](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html) to calculate the value
- You can read from a [CSV file](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), which is the same effect as "[StringFromFile](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile)" but easier to customize and manipulate

Given you have an array of values you could:

- Try the pre-processor ["User
  Parameters"](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters), creating one entry
  for each user/loop
- Use a Beanshell
  script to create the array, select
  one at random and populate your
  variable

You reference them exactly as you have listed: `${varName}`

Comment: I knew about the counter but the identifiers I have aren't consecutive (i.e. 3323, 5512, 2345, ...). I also don't want to read from an external file but simple use something like `${__StringFromArrayAtRandomindex('3', '2', '54', '42')}`

Comment: Given you have an array of specific values, but don't want an external file, I would recommend "User Parameters" or a beanshell script (updated answer)

Comment: @BlackGaffANy help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351587/namestringfromfile-valueerr ?

Answer (score 19):

Concerning implementing `${__StringFromArrayAtRandomIndex('3', '2', '54', '42')}`.

Suppose you can easily implement your scenario using e.g. [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) / [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) with a bit of code.

E.g.:

- Set your source variable (via e.g. [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)):

  ```
  Name        Value          
  categories  3,2,54,42,37
  ```

  (i.e. use comma as delimiter, no spaces before and after comma).
- Use add BeanShell Sampler/PostProcessor with the following code:

  ```
  import java.util.Random;

  String[] categories = (vars.get("categories")).split(",");

  int idx = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
  String category = (categories[idx]);

  vars.put("categoryId", category);
  ```
- Refer further in the script randomly picked form list value as `${categoryId}`.

Comment: Just a typo: vars.put("categoryId", category); Otherwise, jMeter (at least, version 2.9 on Java 6) complains.

Answer (score 17):

To obtain a random variable value from a list, first declare as User variables the list or available values, with a prefix and a incremental index:

```
country_1     Spain 
country_2     France  
country_3     Portugal  
country_4     Italy 
country_5     England
```

Then you can obtain a random value from the list concatenating the prefix with a random index in the interval:

```
${__V(country_${__Random(1,6,)})}  --> "Spain", "France", "Portugal", etc...
```

Take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34229450/2996064) for complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest solution without variables can be done using `vars.getIteration()`:

```
/test/foo.html?id=${__groovy(vars.getIteration())}
```