# Get random values from an array

Tags: jmeter

I defined a new variable

```
Name        Value            Description
categories  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  my categories ids
```

and in my path i want to get a random value from categories: `category_id=my_random_value`.

I even tried this

```
category_id=${__StringFromArrayAtRandomindex('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

__StringFromArrayAtRandomindex is not part of JMeter core nor part of JMeter plugins.

Is it a custom function ?

Furthermore, you have a syntax error (there is a missing ***)*** at end:

```
${__StringFromArrayAtRandomindex('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')}
```

To do the same thing, use a CSV Data Set which will contain:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Set:

```
Variable Names=categoryId
```

You can then use it like this:

```
${categoryId}
```

Comment: no it not a custom function, is there a way to solve this with jmeter?

Answer (score 29):

To obtain a random variable value from a list, first declare as User variables the list or available values, with a prefix and a incremental index:

```
country_1     Spain 
country_2     France  
country_3     Portugal  
country_4     Italy 
country_5     England
```

Then you can obtain a random value from the list concatenating the prefix with a random index in the interval:

```
${__V(country_${__Random(1,6,)})}  --> "Spain", "France", "Portugal", etc...
```

**Explanation**

The [__Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function will give you an index for your interval. To obtain values from 1 to 5, you have to call `__Random(1,6,)`, as it will never reach the MAX value.

The [__V](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function, will obtain the value of the variable with the given name.

```
${__Random(1,6,)}                 --> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
country_${__Random(1,6,)}         --> "country_1", "country_2", etc...
${__V(country_${__Random(1,6,)})} --> "Spain", "France", "Portugal", etc...
```

As example, to use the random variable as JSON body for a request, in Body Data:

```
}
  "country":"${__V(country_${__Random(1,6,)})}"
}
```

Comment: In case it helps anyone, in jMeter 5, `__Random` *will* reach the MAX value.

Answer (score 17):

For your scenario you could try to use the JSR233 components ([Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), [PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)) with a bit of java/[groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) code.

E.g.:

- Define your data as you've done:

  ```
  Name        Value          
  categories  1,2,3,4,5
  ```

  (i.e. use comma as delimiter, no spaces before and after comma).
- Use the JSR233 Sampler / PreProcessor / PostProcessor with the following code:

  ```
  import java.util.Random;

  String[] categories = (vars.get("categories")).split(",");

  int idx = new Random().nextInt(categories.length);
  String category = (categories[idx]);

  vars.put("rnd_cat", category);
  ```
- Refer to the randomly picked category using `${rnd_cat}`.

Comment: `vars.set()` -> `vars.put()`: thanks @Thomas Solti for update.

Comment: This is very good. Say you get an array of ids from a response. you have to remove square brackets `(vars.get("emailAddresses")).replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").split(",");
`