# JMeter - random currency from list

Tags: jmeter

I've got a JMeter test plan that creates a subscription record for a customer. At the moment I need to specify the exact currency to be used, but i'd like to replace this with a variable to automatically pick a currency from a list. We currently use GBP, EUR and USD. I don't know enough about JMeter at the moment to find an easy answer so I do apologise if this is really simple.

Comment: This example perfectly fits your needs http://stackoverflow.com/a/14697370

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is using [User Defined Variables](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65146-using-user-defined-variables-in-jmeter-2-6)

Just add User Defined Variables config element to your Thread Group and populate it as follows:

- currency1 USD
- currency2 EUR
- currency3 GBP

So these are being stored as JMeter Variables.

After somewhere in your test where you need to select a currency you can use following combination:

```
currency${__Random(1,3,)}
```

Where **currency** is a static prefix and **${__Random(1,3,)}** is JMeter [Random Function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) which returns a random number from 1 to 3.