# Jmeter: How to create an array in bean shell post processor and make it available in other thread groups?

Tags: arrays, jmeter, beanshell, post-processing

Does anyone knows how to create an array in bean shell post processor and make it available in other thread groups?

I've been searching for a while and i'm not managing to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: If you need single value then you definitly have to use User Defined Variables. If you need array then I see the only one way: save values into csv file an in other pre-processor read your csv. Can you explain you intention?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to save a random number of id's created in a loop controller and use theses id's in another thread group. For each iteration of the loop i want to append an id to the array.

Comment: You can do it the next way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341600/use-request-value-from-list-of-values-in-jmeter but I would prefer reading CSV.

Comment: Looks like i have no alternative. I'm going to try the CVS approach. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following some advice, here's how i did it:

The HTTP request has a Regular Expressions Extractor to extract the XPTO variable from the request. Then, a BeanShell PostProcessor saves data to a CSV file:

```
String xpto_str = vars.get("XPTO");
log.info("Variable is: " + xpto_str);

f = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/xptos.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(xpto_str + ",");
f.close();
```

Then, in second thread group, i added a CSV Data Set Config, in which i read the variable from the file. This is really easy, just read the guide (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you use property? property variable is accessible across all the thread groups. Writing and reading a file costs a lot of cpu time in terms of load usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do it through writing and reading files. Beanshell extension mechanism is smart enough to handle it without interim 3rd party entities.

Short answer: **bsh.shared** namespace

Long answer:

assuming following Test Plan Structure:

```
Thread Group 1 
    Beanshell Sampler 1
Thread Group 2
    Beahshell Sampler 2
```

Put following Beanshell code to `Beanshell Sampler 1`

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("somekey","somevalue");
bsh.shared.my_cool_map = map;
```

And the following to `Beanshell Sampler 2`

```
Map map = bsh.shared.my_cool_map;
log.info(map.get("somekey"));
```

Run it and look into jmeter.log file. You should see something like

```
2014/01/04 10:32:09 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: somevalue
```

Voila.

References:

1. [Sharing variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) (from JMeter Best Practices)
2. [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide

Comment: Is it possible to iterate trough values using that approach (maybe using thread id as key...) ? In my solution i can easily do that using the CSV Data Set Config. Thnaks

Comment: In case of Map it has keySet and values collections, you can save them to JMeter variables and feed to i.e. For Each Controller

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I will try that next time, to see how it behaves.

Comment: What you need here is Jmeter's propertries: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/jmeter/property